# Put multiple pandas dataframes into one excel sheet in grid format

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

So, I have one very large Dataframe that is composed of over 70 smaller dataframes, of ten rows each. I want to use xlsxwriter to write them into an excel sheet; however, I want the dataframes to be displayed in a grid format, so that they do not simply place going east to west or north to south. My desired output is shown below.

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU9tF.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `startcol` and `startrow` from [DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Use df.shape to get the desired col/row position. Allocate space for the headers